# Android - Hiding ACTION_CALL UI

Tags: android, phone-call

I created a small application that is able to make phone call but I would like to hide the calling screen of this ACTION_CALL so I can read/take measurements.

I created a method that contains the following code and which is called when pressing a button

```
String PhoneNumber = phone_number_edittext.getText().toString();
final Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + PhoneNumber));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

I wondering if I should use service or something else.